# Work done by a pump to empty a well

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, power

I've come across problems that ask to calculate work done by a pump to empty a full cylindrical well. The result obtained through integration is $mgh/2$, where $m$ is the mass of water in the well and $h$ is the depth of the well. But in reality the pipe that drains the water is placed at the bottom of the well. As the bottom-most layer of water is being pumped out, the layer above it comes down due to gravity. In that sense every layer of water is being pumped out from the very bottom of the well. So shouldn't the work done be $mgh$ instead?

Answer (score 3):

The water outside the pipe pushes the water inside the pipe up the pipe until it reaches the same level as the water outside. Then the pump only needs to pump the water from this level.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity is a conservative force (sort of...). That's why water likes to stay level in the first place, no matter of the container geometry.

So, it is not important what a complex path any particle of water travels out of the well. Only the initial and the final positions are important.

You move a body of water with a center of mass at depth h/2 (in the middle of the well) up to zero elevation (you just spill the water at the ground).

Comment: This assumes no frictional losses in the pump or piping.